# How do I change the alignment and bullet style in a multilevel list?

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize

I have a document template that uses a list of items with `id=1`/`id=0` and `\begin{itemize}\onlyitems[none, include = 1]` being used as a show/hide condition for each item. Now I would like add bulletpoints after each item (adding a second level to the list).

The goal is to obtain the equivalent of

```
text 1
\begin{itemize}\onlyitems
..
\end{itemize}

text 2
\begin{itemize}\onlyitems
...
\end{itemize}

...
```

While being able to add/remove new entries without creating a new document.

Removing the bullet from the first level of the list is easy enough, but I'm not sure how to change the alignment so that the first level looks like ordinary text. I also don't know how to change the style of the bullet in the second level from a dash.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

% A huge list of pgfkeys to be set up.  
\pgfkeys{
    /onlyitems/.is family, /onlyitems,
    % Utility keys
    utility/store tag/.store in = \itemOptions,
    utility/store bool/.store in = \itemIf,
    utility/process true/.style = {process/#1 = \iftrue},
    utility/process false/.style = {process/#1 = \iffalse},%\fi
    utility/set store bool/.style 2 args = {#1/.style = {utility/store bool = #2}},
    utility/set select style/.style 2 args = {utility/set store bool = {select/#1}{#2}},
    utility/verdict/.style = {},
    utility/add to reset/.style = {
        reset/.prefix style = {select/#1/.style = {select/.unknown}}
    },
    utility/current key/.estore in = \itemKey,
    % Nothing in the process family is ever set, so any selection option is set to store a boolean
    process/.unknown/.style = {
        utility/current key = \pgfkeyscurrentname,
        select/\itemKey/.style = {
            utility/set store bool = {utility/verdict}{#1}
        },
        utility/add to reset/.expand once = \itemKey
    },
    % For clearing the list of selected items (to support nested {itemize})
    reset/.style = {},
    reset/reset/.style = {reset/.style = {reset/reset, default}},
    reset/reset,
    % Here are the options you can actually pass.  These go to the {itemize}...
    include/.style = {utility/process true/.list  = {#1}},
    exclude/.style = {utility/process false/.list = {#1}},
    all/.style  = {utility/set select style = {.unknown}{\iftrue}},
    none/.style = {utility/set select style = {.unknown}{\iffalse}},%\fi
    default/.style = {all},
    % ...and these to the \item's
    tag/.style = {utility/store tag = {[#1]}},
    id/.style = {select/#1},
}

% Like tikzset, it sets a default key path
\newcommand\onlyitemsset[1]{\pgfkeys{/onlyitems, #1}}

\let\itemLaTeX=\item
% Have to use a \newcount because (ugh) the LaTeX \setcounter is a global assignment
\newcount\itemsSoFar
\renewcommand\item[1][]{%
    % The \egroup closes off any \vbox'es from the previously ignored \item.
    % The conditional \bgroup cancels it out when there aren't any.
    \itemIf\bgroup\fi\egroup
    \let\itemIf=\iffalse%\fi
    \advance\itemsSoFar by 1 %
    \onlyitemsset{utility/store tag = {}, utility/verdict/.style = {}, select/\the\itemsSoFar, #1, utility/verdict}%
    \itemIf
    \def\next{\expandafter\itemLaTeX\itemOptions}%
    \else
    % The vbox is set and then discarded, effectively ignoring an entire \item.
    % This inner \itemLaTeX is necessary to avoid a glitch when we ignore the first \item of an itemize that itself contains a nested \itemize.  Don't ask, I don't know.
    \def\next{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\itemLaTeX}%
    \fi
    \next
}

% \let\itemizeLaTeX=\itemize
% \let\enditemizeLaTeX=\enditemize
% \renewcommand\itemize[1][]{%
%  \let\itemIf=\iftrue
%  \itemsSoFar = 0 %
%  % We have to reset here so that the selections from an outer itemize don't conflict with an inner one.
%  \onlyitemsset{reset, #1}%
%  \itemizeLaTeX
% }
% \renewcommand\enditemize{%
%  % This closes off the last \vbox
%  \itemIf\bgroup\fi\egroup\enditemizeLaTeX
% }

\newcommand\onlyitems[2][]{%
    \let\itemIf=\iftrue
    \itemsSoFar = 0 %
    % We have to reset here so that the selections from an outer itemize don't conflict with an inner one.
    \onlyitemsset{reset, #1}%
    #2%
    % This closes off the last \vbox
    \itemIf\bgroup\fi\egroup
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mylist}{
    \item[id = 1] item 1 text
        \begin{itemize}\onlyitems
            \item point 1
            \item point 2
            \item point 3
        \end{itemize}
    \item[id = 0] item 2 text
        \begin{itemize}\onlyitems
            \item point 1
            \item point 2
            \item point 3
        \end{itemize}
    \item[id = 1] item 3 text
        \begin{itemize}\onlyitems
            \item point 1
            \item point 2
            \item point 3
        \end{itemize}
}

\begin{itemize}\onlyitems[none, include = 1]
    \mylist
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you get `\onlyitems` from? Can you transform your code snippet into a complete, minimal example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Werner Added__

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, with LaTeX complaining about the macro you've named `\list_name`.

Comment: @Mico \list_name is just a stand-in for the desired name of the list. I will change it so that it compiles.

Comment: @Mico the code in the edit should compile.

Comment: @R.Burton - Thanks for this. I must confess to not being all that familiar with either LaTeX's list environments or pgfkeys, and hence to not being in a position to offer advice on your query.

Comment: @Mico the pgfkeys doesn't effect the format of the list, it only controls which items are shown/hidden. That's why I didn't originally post it. It should be possible to shift the alignment of a list left and change the bullet style of the `itemize` environment without using pgfkeys at all.